# Predict_proba function for Multi-target Classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I am working on a Multi-Target (binary) classification. There are 11 targets and I am using sklearn's MultiOutputClassifier. I am having difficulty with the Predict_proba function. See a snippet of the dataset, and code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as npy
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier

data = pd.read_csv("123.csv")
```

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eENtH.png)

```
target = ['H67BC97','H67GC93','H67LC63','H67WC103','H67RC91','H67YC73','H67RC92','H67GC94','H67LC64','H67NC60','H67YC72']
train, test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2)
X_train = train.drop(['H67BC97','H67GC93','H67LC63','H67WC103','H67RC91','H67YC73','H67RC92','H67GC94','H67LC64','H67NC60','H67YC72','FORMULA_NUMBER'],axis=1)
X_test = test.drop(['H67BC97','H67GC93','H67LC63','H67WC103','H67RC91','H67YC73','H67RC92','H67GC94','H67LC64','H67NC60','H67YC72','FORMULA_NUMBER'],axis=1)
Y_train = train[target]
Y_test = test[target]

model = MultiOutputClassifier(GradientBoostingClassifier())
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
target_probabilities = model.predict_proba(X_test)
print(target_probabilities)
```

[probabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJlpL.png)

The probabilities output do not seem to be in the correct form. I get 11 565x2 arrays (565 is length of my test set). I'd like to save the target_probabilities to a csv file, but I get the error: ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 3D array instead. My question is essentially the same as on the link -
 https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22762/understanding-predict-proba-from-multioutputclassifier, but the answer there only explains why the output is a set of arrays.

EDIT: I have simplified the problem.

```
target_probabilities = array(target_probabilities)
```

Now target_probabilities is an (11,565,2) matrix - need to change the form of the matrix to be (565,11), where each row is of the form target_probabilities[:,i][:,1], for i in the range(0,565).

Comment: That should be easy. For each list (output), you have a 2-d array. Use [1,:] from them. This will convert your 3-d to 2-d array of [11, 565]. Take transpose of that to array it into [565, 11], where each column represents the probability of positive class for output. Comment if still not get that and we can provide an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Was surprisingly straightforward :)